# Illustrator shadow layer inside a layer with stroke?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, illustration

I am having a tough time with creating a shadow, I am using strokes so when I want to create a darker tone inside the characters neck the stroke becomes a problem.

1. The neck before the shadow.

[image]

2. Duplicating the neck layer.

[image]

3. Matching the layers and darkening the second layer

[image]

4. Adjusting the shadow layer

[image]

You can see in step 4 the inner neck now has an unwanted stroke, I would like to adjust the shadow layer down to give it that shadow effect, but the shadow layer cannot overlap the stroke, i.e

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: Blending Modes. Set the shadow layers blending mode. Probably to 'darken' or 'multiply' but see what works best.

[image]

Option 2: Separate layers. Split the main color and stroke to different layers then place the shadow layer between those layers. So you have the bottom layer as the fill but without the stroke, then the shadow layer, then a layer with only the stroke and no fill

[image]

Comment: Thanks man will do, I saw someone on youtube do blending modes option but it was so fast I couldnt figure out.. This helps!

Comment: No problem. Blending modes are definitely useful!